# How to parse a firebase real time database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How I can parse firebase realtime database?

So far my code is:

```
var ref: DatabaseReference!
ref = Database.database().reference()
ref.child("data").observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
   print("snapshot = \(snapshot)")
}
```

I can not enter the condition. 
[image]

```
print("url = \(ref.url)")
url = "https://gdenamaz.firebaseio.com"
```

this variant don't work too

```
var ref: DatabaseReference!
    ref = Database.database().reference().child("data")

    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        for data in snapshot.children {
            print("data = \(data)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: println(snapshot.value)

Comment: I can not enter the condition

Comment: You need to get the snapshot.value like.  <code>  for data in snapshot.value {
            print("data = \(data)")
        } </code>

Answer (score 0):

To reference the official docs -

```
refHandle = postRef.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
  let postDict = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] ?? [:]
  // ...
})
```

You want to be looking for the `snapshot.value` not `snapshot.children`

A further example

```
let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
ref.child("users").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
  // Get user value
  let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
  let username = value?["username"] as? String ?? ""
  let user = User(username: username)

  // ...
  }) { (error) in
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

also, `.childAdded` will only trigger when a child is added. IE, nothing will happen until you actually change something in that node reference.